# Execution Time Mongodb 0 but there is a delay on the Client side

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im using mlab sandbox for my server, and is using node.js express for backend. the  problem is with the retrieval time of data from mlab to client. based on the executionStats on mongoDB there was 0 executionTimemills but when i try to get the data through postman there's an average of 500ms of time and 600B of size. i tried to trace where the delay is coming from. and its on the promise on the backend, basically the test was to post the current time before the query fires *(pp_query)* and compare it to the time of the returned promise *(pp_res)*. i used async function and await. is it normal to have that delay even we have 0 executiontimemillis on MongoDb? if so, is 500ms too long for a 600B size of data? thank you

1. This is my Async function:

   ```
   async function suggestedPrice(itemCode,customerId,qty){
     var priceCatega = priceCateg(itemCode);
     var aitemHis = itemHistory_c(itemCode,customerId);
     var apriceCat = priceCategoryHistory_c(customerId, await priceCatega)

     var itemHis = await aitemHis;
     var priceCat =  await apriceCat;
     return {itemHis,priceCat};
   }
   ```
2. These are the methods:

   ```
   const itemHistory_c = (itemCode,customerId) =>{ 
      var pp_query = speedTest(); //states the current timestamp
      var x = deploySalesOrders.find({itemCode,customerId})
      x.select('date discount price offer');
      x.limit(1);
      x.sort({date:-1})
      //x.explain("executionStats");
      return x.exec()
       .then((itemHis) => {
           var pp_res = speedTest();
           // return itemHis;
           var g;
           if(!isEmpty(itemHis)){
               var date_IH = itemHis[0].date;
               var disc_IH = itemHis[0].discount;
               var unitPrice_IH = itemHis[0].price;
               var offer = itemHis[0].offer;
               var origin = "itemHis";
               g = {date : date_IH,unitPrice : unitPrice_IH,disc : disc_IH,offer,origin}
           }
           var post_res= speedTest();
           g = {...itemHis,pp_query,pp_res,post_res}
           return g;  

       })

     }

   const priceCategoryHistory_c = (customerId,priceCategory) =>{   
   var x;
   if(priceCategory != ''){ 
       var pp_query = speedTest();
       var y = deploySalesOrders.find({$and:[{priceCategory},{customerId}]})
       y.select('date discount price offer itemCode controlNo_DSI')
       y.sort("-date")
       y.limit(1)
       return y.exec()
       .then((priceCatHis) =>{
           var pp_res = speedTest();
           if(!isEmpty(priceCatHis)){
               var date_IH = priceCatHis[0].date;
               var disc_IH = priceCatHis[0].discount;
               var unitPrice_IH = priceCatHis[0].price;
               var offer = priceCatHis[0].offer;
               var itemCode = priceCatHis[0].itemCode;
               var controlNo_DSI = priceCatHis[0].controlNo_DSI
               var origin = "priceCat";
               x = {date : date_IH,unitPrice : unitPrice_IH,disc : disc_IH, priceCategory,offer,itemCode,controlNo_DSI,origin}//,purchase}
           }
           var post_res= speedTest();
           x = {...x,pp_query,pp_res,post_res}   
           return x;  
       // return priceCatHis
       })    
     }
   }   
     const priceCateg = (itemCode) =>{
     var x = ItemTrial.find({itemCode})
     x.select('price.priceCategory')
     x.sort('-date')
     x.limit(1)
     return x.exec()
      .then((price) =>{
      if (price.length > 0){
           return price[0].price.priceCategory;
      } 
      else{
           return '';
      }   
    });
   }
   ```
3. Router

   ```
    router.use('/suggestions',(req,res)=>{
       try{   
           suggestedPrice(req.query.itemCode, req.query.customerId,req.query.totalQty)
           .then((a) => {
             res.status(200).send(a)
           })
       }
       catch(err){
          res.json({err});
       }
     })
   ```
4. Result From postman

   ```
   {
      "itemHis": {
         "0": {
            "_id": "5bd6bc275d7de933b4ecb4b6",
            "date": "2019-10-29T16:21:00.000Z",
            "price": 0,
            "discount": "L-12%",
            "offer": ""
          },
          "pp_query": "13:25:34:587",
          "pp_res": "13:25:34:873",
          "post_res": "13:25:34:873"
        },
        "priceCat": {
           "date": "2019-06-21T16:21:00.000Z",
           "unitPrice":0,
           "disc": "L-12%",
           "priceCategory": "abc",
           "offer": "",
           "itemCode": "abc_code",
           "controlNo_DSI": "abc-0357-2",
           "origin": "priceCat",
           "pp_query": "13:25:34:863",
           "pp_res": "13:25:35:115",
           "post_res": "13:25:35:115"
         }
     }
   ```

Comment: Please share the code base. Specifically the one where you're returning the promise.

Comment: pp_query is a time stamp before the execution of query and pp_res is the a timestamp after getting the promise from mongoDB thank you @planet_hunter snippet of codes are posted above

Comment: @G.Sy please update the question to include the code instead of posting a link to a screenshot of the code. A good guideline to follow is [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: okay thank you sir @KevinAdistambha, i've edited the post. whats the normal retrieval time from a remote database? is my situation normal (time : 500ms, Size : 600B ) thank you sir.

Comment: @G.Sy just to quickly comment on this, "normal" could be different in different situation, so it's difficult to judge what is "normal". If you ping the server, does it return in 500ms as well? Having said that, the mLab sandbox environment is the free offering which from the website implies a best-effort shared environment, so you definitely should take this into account. From such an environment, I would not expect it to be fast.